# Puppet data array

Tags: puppet, hiera

I got a module that creating some directories depending of server:

```
class linux_sftp::sftp_mount ($sftp_mount_ip, $sftp_mount_username, $sftp_mount_password, $sftp_mount_point) {

  file { "/mnt/${sftp_mount_point}":
    ensure => directory,
    subscribe => Exec['sftp_remount'],
  }
```

in data.yml

```
sftp_mount_point: "stcontent1"
```

I want to add to data more folders like: stcontent2, stcontent3. Is it a way to add this and loop thru data?

```
sftp_mount_point: 
  - "stcontent1"
  - "stcontent2" ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use lambda method (can also be invoked as functions if desired) iteration to accomplish this task. The most common for your use case is `each`. It can be easily invoked on type `Array[String]` like you  have in your question.

```
$sftp_mount_point.each |String $mount| {
  file { "/mnt/${mount}":
    ensure => directory,
  }
}
```

Note that the `file` type does not have a `subscribable` property, so `subscribe` is not a valid attribute and I therefore removed it above.